Fully quantized int8 tflite file size larger than original unquantized files?
I am exporting YOLOv11n model trained on custom dataset to tflite with int8 quantization for deploying in edgetpu however the output model compiled is larger than the original input file.
Why is it larger what was going wrong ?

Python version 3.8
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO("best (1).pt")

model.export(format="tflite", int8=True,data='data.yaml' )

